# Splitting a comma-separated field in Postgresql and doing a UNION ALL on all the resulting tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I have a table that contains a field of comma separated strings:

```
ID | fruits
-----------
1  | cherry,apple,grape 
2  | apple,orange,peach
```

I want to create a normalized version of the table, like this:

```
ID | fruits
-----------
1  | cherry 
1  | apple 
1  | grape
2  | apple 
2  | orange 
2  | peach
```

The postgresql 8.4 documentation describes a regexp_split_to_table function that can turn a single table:

```
SELECT foo 
FROM regexp_split_to_table('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog',E'\\s+') AS
foo;
```

which gives you this:

```
  foo   
--------
  the    
  quick  
  brown  
  fox    
  jumped 
  over   
  the    
  lazy   
  dog    
 (9 rows)
```

But that is just for a single field. What I want to do is some kind UNION applied to all the tables generated by splitting each field. Thank you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This should give you the output you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
    yourTable.ID, 
    regexp_split_to_table(yourTable.fruits, E',') AS split_fruits
FROM yourTable
```

EDIT: Fixed the regex.

Comment: can you please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005974/convert-comma-seperated-db-items-to-isolated-rows

Comment: i tried SELECT CATEGORI.ID, regexp_split_to_table(CATEGORI.CATEGORY, E',') AS split_fruits FROM CATEGORI;

Comment: it works but i want to filter duplicate data from it

Comment: What's the E for?