# Convert comma seperated db items to isolated rows

Tags: java, postgresql

I have got the following table datas.. Table name is category

```
| ID             | Data                     | 
+----------------+--------------------------+
| 1              | Apple,Orance-........... | 
| 2              | Apple,Grapes-........... | 
| 3              | Juice,Apple,Cucumber-... |
```

Is there by any means that I could convert the above comma seperated values to that of inividual rows as below?

```
| ID          | SplitData
+-------------+-------------------
| 1           | Apple
| 2           | Orange
| 3           | Grapes
| 4           | Juice
| 5           | Cucumber
```

Im using postgres for db and Jersey to retrieve data,

Comment: Hint use `Set` and `sort`

Comment: can you please elobrate

Comment: You can probably also use PostgreSQL table and array functions in SQL

Comment: i tried SELECT ARRAY_AGG(CATEGORY) FROM CATEGORI; but it is not filtering duplicate data

Comment: Java solution is create a Set and then split `Data` in array of string and for each string in the array put the string in Set. Since set don't allow duplicates, therefore, there will be no duplicates. Then you can sort the collection alphabatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `string_to_array()` in `unnest()`:

```
with a_table(id, data) as (
    values
        (1, 'Apple,Orance'),
        (2, 'Apple,Grapes'),
        (3, 'Juice,Apple,Cucumber')
)

select id, elem
from a_table,
lateral unnest(string_to_array(data, ',')) elem

 id |   elem   
----+----------
  1 | Apple
  1 | Orance
  2 | Apple
  2 | Grapes
  3 | Juice
  3 | Apple
  3 | Cucumber
(7 rows)
```

Use `distinct` to get distinct elements:

```
with a_table(id, data) as (
    values
        (1, 'Apple,Orance'),
        (2, 'Apple,Grapes'),
        (3, 'Juice,Apple,Cucumber')
)

select distinct on (elem) elem
from a_table,
lateral unnest(string_to_array(data, ',')) elem

   elem   
----------
 Apple
 Cucumber
 Grapes
 Juice
 Orance
(5 rows)
```

Comment: I tried select ID, CATEGORY from CATEGORI, lateral unnest(string_to_array(data, ',')) elem

Comment: it prints ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 2: select * from categori;
        ^

Comment: I'm not able to debug a query i can't see. Use this to test: [rextester](http://rextester.com/AHUH64608).